# Cannot install wine7 ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, wine, 22.04

cannot install wine7 on ubuntu 22.04

i have used the instructions on winehq but got

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 7.0.0.0~focal-1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The instructions on winehq:

```
$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

which have no output

then

```
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
```

outputs

```
--2022-05-08 12:41:22--  https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:7899... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 3220 (3.1K) [application/pgp-keys]
Saving to: ‘winehq.key’

winehq.key             100%[============================>]   3.14K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2022-05-08 12:41:24 (41.3 MB/s) - ‘winehq.key’ saved [3220/3220]
```

then

```
sudo mv winehq.key /usr/share/keyrings/winehq-archive.key
```

which is a move

then

```
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/jammy/winehq-jammy.sources
```

output:

```
--2022-05-08 12:43:36--  https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/jammy/winehq-jammy.sources
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:7899... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 165
Saving to: ‘winehq-jammy.sources’

winehq-jammy.sources   100%[============================>]     165  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2022-05-08 12:43:38 (12.4 MB/s) - ‘winehq-jammy.sources’ saved [165/165]
```

then the

```
sudo apt update
```

output:

```
Hit:1 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                              
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                           
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                             
Hit:4 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease         
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                
Hit:6 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
3 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

then for the stable branch

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 7.0.0.0~focal-1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**update**

I have successfuly installed a wine with the

```
sudo apt install wine
```

command, but it doesn't have an interface and I don't know if it is working properly.

Comment: To increase your odds of getting help, edit your question and show the full input and output including all details. We don't necessarily know what "the instructions on winehq" are.

Comment: The version of winehq is "focal". **You cannot install packages compiled against an old Ubuntu version (20.04==focal) on your current version (Ubuntu 22.04==jammy)**

Comment: How do i remove packages that are not installed?

Comment: wine doesn't really have a gui. You can run `winecfg` in a terminal, that's about as much of a gui as it has.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you for using 'Bottles' for running win apps.

you will find it here-
https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.usebottles.bottles